# Extract the required part from same type of URLs in notepad+++ by regex

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

I have a list of URLs from same website. How can I extract a particular part of them using regex in Notepad++?

Here is a part of the URLs:

```
https://www.example.in/example/MT60B2G8HB-48BA-TR?qs=iLbezkQI%252BsgqYFd1yfooJw%3D%3D
https://www.example.in/example/AT25L128A-MHE-T?qs=IS%252B4QmGtzzoXQyQfwYv36A%3D%3D
```

Output should be `MT60B2G8HB-48BA-TR` & `AT25L128A-MHE-T` from all the similar type of URLs.

Comment: Only the domain i.e www.example.com remains the same after that /example/ differs according to the subcategories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short alternative as usual

Find:`^.*/(.*?)\?.*`

Replace with:`$1`

Answer (score 0):

If all URLs have the same url, path up until the last part & do always have GET-parameters (using `?`), then you can use this:

```
"(?<=https://www.example.in/example/)[^?]+"
# match any string that has https://www.example.in/example/ before it until the first ?
```

If it is optional whether the url has GET-params:

```
"(?<=https://www.example.in/example/)[^?\s]+"
# match any string that has https://www.example.in/example/ before it until the first ? or whitespace/linebreak
```

Comment: well only the domain i.e www.example.com remains the same after that /example/ differs according to the subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

the following will allow you to **search** for the pattern (in regex mode of course) :

```
(?<=https://www.example.in/example/).*(?=\?)
```

`(?<=...)` is called positive lookbehind and must be a fixed pattern positioned before what you are looking for

`(?=...)` is called positive lookahead and must be a fixed pattern positioned after what you are looking for (here the first '?' escaped with '\')

If you want to **replace** the pattern then you can simplify to this.

Find what : `https://www.example.in/example/(.*)\?.*`
Replace with : `$1`